# Adding elements in arrays that fall within a criteria in Python

Tags: python, arrays, addition

I am trying to add two matrices together, however, I only want to add it to certain elements in an array that fall under a predetermined criteria.  For example, say I have an 2D (2x2) RGB array of:

```
[[[ 0.          0.          0.5       ]
 [ 0.89500316  1.          0.07273877]]

 [[ 0.          0.          0.5       ]
  [ 0.          0.          0.5       ]]]
```

I want to impose the condition that adds `[0, 0, 1]` to elements corresponding to blue that are `less than 0.1` so the output would be:

```
[[[ 0.          0.          0.5       ]
 [ 0.89500316  1.          1.07273877]]

 [[ 0.          0.          0.5       ]
  [ 0.          0.          0.5       ]]]
```

How would I go about this?  I already have set up but it obviously adds `1` to all of the elements in the third column:

```
a = a + [0, 0, 1]
print a
```

Comment: Are you using numpy for this? With numpy, the expression you wrote might do element-wise addition. With standard Python (not numpy), it will just append a 1D list to the end of your matrix.

Comment: Yes, I am using numpy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your RGB values are just float in it, one way to do it would be to use boolean *masks* to select your data:

```
>>> a[:, :, 2][a[:, :, 2] < 0.1] += 1.0
```

Or even, selecting only the 'column' you want to change:

```
>>> view = a[:, :, 2]
>>> view[view < 0.1] += 1.0
```

**EDIT**

In Numpy, arrays can be indexed via integers (like you'd expect), but also via boolean masks, telling which element to take or not:

```
>>> foo = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
>>> mask = np.array([[True, False], [False, True]])
>>> foo[mask]
array([1, 4])
```

Since boolean operations work elementwise on arrays, this lets you 'select' elements matching a criterion:

```
>>> foo[foo > 2]
array([3, 4])
```

In addition, taking such a selection returns a *view* on the original array, so these elements can be mutated in the original array:

```
>>> foo[foo % 2 == 0] += 1
>>> foo
array([[1, 3],
       [3, 5]])
```

Comment: The first one adds one to everything in that row for some reason but the second is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Ooops, you're right, I was applying my mask to the wrong array; this is corrected now. Thanks for pointing that out !